# Why can I not join a game on Minecraft xbox360?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have the gold membership and I am connected but when I open up Minecraft the join game section says no games found. Why Is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Minecraft for the Xbox 360, playing online doesn't feature a classic server setup like you see on its PC counterpart. Instead, you are able to join your friends' games should they set their gametype appropriately, or through private invitation.